# REDIS OM .NET - InvalidOperationException when grouping

Tags: c#, .net, redis, redis-om

I keep getting this exception when performing a simple linq group query using the [Redis OM library](https://redis.io/docs/stack/get-started/tutorials/stack-dotnet/):

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Searches can only be performed on
> objects decorated with a RedisObjectDefinitionAttribute that specifies
> a particular index'

My code:

```
Agents = (RedisCollection<Agent>)RedisProvider.RedisCollection<Agent>();
var groups = Agents.GroupBy(x => x.AccountId);
foreach (var group in groups)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{group.Key}");
}
```

My indexed model:

```
[Document(StorageType = StorageType.Json, Prefixes = new[] { "Agent" })]
public class Agent
{
        [RedisIdField]
        [Indexed] public string Id { get; set; }

        [Indexed(Sortable = true, Aggregatable = true)]
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
}
```

The index is created in Redis and I am able to perform Where() queries in Linq successfully on the same redis collection, interestingly group.Count() also works correctly. It is just once I try to iterate over group items it throws this exception.

I've done some Googling but cannot find a solution or info on the 'Redis Object Definition Attribute' the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to run a `GroupBy` in Redis against the `RedisCollection`, that's not a valid operation. You can materialize your collection (call `ToList` or some other enumeration on it), prior to running the GroupBy, or you can run a `GroupBy` in the context of a RedisAggregationSet, which will allow you to do run [reductions against it](https://developer.redis.com/develop/dotnet/redis-om-dotnet/aggregations/groups/groups).

The tradeoff here is if you want to run the `GroupBy` post-materialization, you have to pull the whole result set back and have your app cobble everything into a group. If you do it within the context of the `RedisAggregationSet`, all the processing can be done server side.